# Long boot time of a new window in iterm2 on Macbook Pro M1 Pro

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, iterm2

I have been using iterm for a few years. I have recently switched to a new macbook M1 Pro and had to reinstall everything. I use zsh with powerlevek10k however when I open a new terminal in iterm it takes more than 10seconds to load! It's opening so many stuff before it jumps to zsh. It goes like this: Default login Default bash Default sort Default env Default Python zsh

Any tips how can I troubleshoot this?